Можно ли использовать только IP-адрес, и не использовать MAC-адрес?
Может ли все это функционировать таким образом как я описал ниже, а все работает так как есть просто потому что это так исторически сложилось?
Предположим что на устройствах не будет MAC-адресов.
Тогда коммутатор будет создавать таблицы соответствия не MAС, а IP-адресов портам.
При включении хосты могут присваивать себе рандомный IP адрес и запрашивать новый у DHCP-сервера.
Да, нужно будет изменить заголовки IP-пакета таким образом чтобы в нем появился еще один, третий адрес: 1-адрес отправителя, 2-адрес конечного получателя, 3-адрес следующего получателя(например шлюза). Первый и второй неизменны, а третий может изменяться при прохождении пакета по сети.
Тогда при отправке пакета компьютер проверяет в свою ли сеть отправляется пакет согласно маске подсети.  Если в свою, то второй и третий адрес будут одинаковы. Потому что конечный и следующий адрес один и тот же.
Если же не в свою, то второй адрес - это будет адрес конечногополучателя, а третим адресом укажется адрес шлюза. Шлюз проверяет подключена ли к нему эта сеть, и если нет, то отправляет следующему маршрутизатору и т.д.
Понятно что придется поменять все коммутаторы на соответствующие новым стандартам и написать новый софт.
Вопрос чисто теоретический: нужны ли два адреса или можно обойтись одним.
Немного сумбурно, но попрошу не сильно пинать за это.

MAC адрес существует только в "ethernet-подобных" сетях. Если реализовать IP, например, на телефонной сети (используя модемы), то никаких привычных MAC в сети не будет (правда вместо них на канальном (Data Link) уровне появятся телефонные номера)

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он совсем не касается программирования.

Такое впечатление, что вы пытаетесь разобраться в сетевых технологиях, чего-то не понимаете и пытаетесь заместить это какой-то своей моделью. Просто почитайте про сети что-нибудь хорошее. Возможно, попозже найду что-то для рекомендации и напишу.

Почитайте про IPv6, там некоторые подобные вопросы решены костылями.

А использование случайного IP может привести к конфлитку адресов, именно для этого к IPv4 и приделали DHCP.

balbes, а как же не получается конфликта адресов с использованием APIPA? Нет, DHCP придумали не для этого. И если вы почитаете вопрос еще раз то увидите что случайный адрес нужен временно для получения нового по DHCP.

rotabor, да, все верно. Я изучаю сейчас сетевые технологии. Да, этот вопрос не касается программирования, но разве этот сайт только для программистов? Этот сайт и для системных администраторов, изучите приветственную страницу.

Два узла одновременно подключаются к сети, и случайно выбирают один и тот же адрес, как быть?

balbes, "Два узла одновременно подключаются к сети, и случайно выбирают один и тот же адрес, как быть?"
Хороший вопрос, но я думаю что нибудь придумать можно. Напримет, после выбора одинаковых адресов они оба шлют запрос DHCP серверу и в ходе 4 шагов один из них получает новый адрес. Если же и через, например, 2 попытки ничего не получилось, то возникает понимание что этот адрес дублируется и случайный адрес меняестя на другой случайный. Я придумал это просто чтобы показать что что-то сделать можно, а не как полностью верное решение.

Если бы мы использовали IP-адреса на 2 (L2) уровне, возникла бы проблема «динамики» адресов. В канальном уровне требуется постоянная привязка устройства к порту на коммутаторе, но IP-адреса могут динамически изменяться (DHCP, а если они с каждым входом через DHCP меняются). Это разрушило бы модель «быстрой и стабильной» привязки устройства к порту, что жизненно важно для сетей.
Коммутаторы должны будут отслеживать динамические IP-адреса, что усложнит логику обработки пакетов и увеличит нагрузку на оборудование. Обычно маршрутизаторы (L3-устройства) работают с IP-адресами, потому что они разделяют сеть на домены вещания, что позволяет ограничить количество трафика и предотвращает рассылку ненужных широковещательных сообщений. Если бы коммутаторы работали с IP-адресами, это привело бы к дополнительным затратам времени на анализ пакета (так как в IP-пакете больше данных, чем в MAC-заголовке), а также к необходимости обновления таблиц с привязками IP к портам при каждом изменении IP-адреса.
Локальные сети не могут больше функционировать так же эффективно. Представим, что у нас есть офисная сеть с тысячами устройств. В нынешней архитектуре каждый коммутатор знает MAC-адрес каждого устройства и через ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) привязывает этот адрес к IP-адресу при необходимости. Если убрать MAC-адреса, коммутаторы вынуждены будут строить свои таблицы маршрутизации на основе IP-адресов, но IP-адреса меняются, а это приведет к бесконечным перестройкам таблиц.
Мак адреса относительно простые а если их заменить ipv6 или даже ipv4 то это лишний раз замедлит локальные сети
Eсли IP-адреса используются и на канальном уровне, и на сетевом уровне, устройства внутри одной и той же физической сети могут не иметь стабильных привязок к портам. В случае изменения IP-адреса (например, при повторном подключении устройства или изменении конфигурации DHCP), коммутатор должен будет обновлять свои таблицы привязки IP-адресов к портам. Это приведёт к хаосу и коллизиям в пересылке пакетов, так как сетевое оборудование не сможет быстро определить, где находится конечное устройство в физической сети. Это можно сказать  делает современные сети гибкими, масштабируемыми и устойчивыми к динамическим изменениям, если есть какие либо вопросы и тому прочее могу с радостью ответить

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! на всякий случай: Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?

И вам добрый день. Не соглашусь вообще ни с чем из вашего ответа.
"В канальном уровне требуется постоянная привязка устройства к порту на коммутаторе" - что значит постоянная? Привязка требуется, но она живет пока живет запись в таблице MAC-адресов коммутатора. Знаете ли вы сколько это секунд? Вы и отключиться и включиться за это время вряд ли успеете. Не вижу разницы.

"Обычно маршрутизаторы (L3-устройства) работают с IP-адресами, потому что они разделяют сеть на домены вещания, что позволяет ограничить количество трафика и предотвращает рассылку ненужных широковещательных сообщений" - Ну так для этого есть линк локал адреса.

"В нынешней архитектуре каждый коммутатор знает MAC-адрес каждого устройства и через ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) привязывает этот адрес к IP-адресу при необходимости." - в нынешней архитектуре коммутаторы работают с МАС адресами.

"Мак адреса относительно простые а если их заменить ipv6 или даже ipv4 то это лишний раз замедлит локальные сети" - МАС адреса больше по размеру ipv4. Да, ipv6 больше по размеру чем МАС, но это не сделает большой разницы, особенно учитывая не оптимизированный по современным стандартам заголовок кадра.
"Это приведёт к хаосу и коллизиям в пересылке пакетов" - какие коллизии в дуплексе?

"Eсли IP-адреса используются и на канальном уровне, и на сетевом уровне, устройства внутри одной и той же физической сети могут не иметь стабильных привязок к портам" - о каких постоянных, стабильных привязках вы все время говорите? Нет таких. Есть запись в таблице коммутатора о соответствии порта МАС адресу, у которой ограниченное время жизни и уж оно точно не сохраняется после отключения устройства от сети.

Для себя я , вообще то, уже нашел ответ, точнее пришел к нему. Что все работает так как есть просто потому что это так исторически сложилось. А если бы это проектировалось сейчас, то все было бы по другому, с учетом современных реалий и знаний.

Всем привет и спасибо за участие в поисках ответа на вопрос.
Для себя я , вообще то, уже нашел ответ, точнее пришел к нему. Что все работает так как есть просто потому что это так исторически сложилось. А если бы это проектировалось сейчас, то все было бы по другому, с учетом современных реалий и знаний.

Всё очень просто: канальный уровень (L2) аппаратно зависим и служит для пересылки IP-пакетов в пределах одной IP-сети. MAC-адреса - это частный случай такой аппаратной реализации, именуемой Ethernet. А помимо Ethernet существует ещё множество других технологий, в которых MAC-адресов нет. И все их надо как-то объединить. Для этого и существует аппаратно независимый уровень IP-адресов (L3). Плюс такое разделение уровней даёт возможность централизованного администрирования IP-сетей через DHCP, что было бы невозможно в случае объединения L3 с L2.

LShadow77, очень грамотно сказано, согласен почти со всем.
Только не "канальный уровень (L2) аппаратно зависим и служит для пересылки IP-пакетов в пределах одной IP-сети", а для пересылки кадров в одной канальной среде.
И за исключением того что работа DHCP была бы невозможна. Об этом уже говорилось в предыдущих комментариях.
И это также не отрицает что все это работает так потому что это так исторически сложилось.
